# Identifying the Most Influential Independent Variable on a Dependent Variable with Ordinal Data in R

Tags: r, data-science, data-analysis, lme4

I'm working on a data analysis project using R, and I have a dataset where I'm investigating the relationship between a dependent variable, "Mean_Pe_ratio," and several independent variables in columns 6 to 25. These independent variables represent dietary consumption levels on an ordinal scale (1 - frequent consumption, 5 - low consumption).

```
> PV_idbmdb_groupGene
# A tibble: 207,335 × 25
# Groups:   Gene [791]
   ID      Gene Mean_Pe_ratio gene_count Status SoftDrinks DietSoftDrinks FruitJuice Water
   <chr>  <dbl>         <dbl>      <int> <chr>       <dbl>          <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1 CSM5M…     7        0.137         114 CD              5              5          5     1
 2 CSM5M…  3779        0.0160       1154 CD              5              5          5     1
 3 CSM5M…  3793        0.271        1069 CD              5              5          5     1
 4 CSM5M…  3794        0.140        1109 CD              5              5          5     1
 5 CSM5M…  3795        0.294        1069 CD              5              5          5     1
 6 CSM5M…  3796        0.0161       1130 CD              5              5          5     1
 7 CSM5M…  4588        0.0143       1072 CD              5              5          5     1
 8 CSM5M…  4589        0.0136       1043 CD              5              5          5     1
 9 CSM5M…  4590        0.0279       1052 CD              5              5          5     1
10 CSM5M…  9490        0.198         133 CD              5              5          5     1
# ℹ 207,325 more rows
# ℹ 16 more variables: Alcohol <dbl>, FoodwActiveBactCult <dbl>, Dairy <dbl>,
#   Probiotics <dbl>, FruitsNoJuice <dbl>, Vegetables <dbl>, PlantBasedProteins <dbl>,
#   WholeGrains <dbl>, Starch <dbl>, Eggs <dbl>, ProcessedMeat <dbl>, RedMeat <dbl>,
#   WhiteMeat <dbl>, Shellfish <dbl>, Fish <dbl>, Sweets <dbl>
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

I'd like to determine which independent variables have the most significant impact on the "Mean_Pe_ratio" dependent variable. Moreover, I want to understand the direction of this impact (whether it results in a higher or lower "Mean_Pe_ratio").

```
model1 <- lmer(Pe_ratio ~ SoftDrinks + DietSoftDrinks + FruitJuice +        
           Water + Alcohol + FoodwActiveBactCult + Dairy + Probiotics + FruitsNoJuice + Vegetables +   
           PlantBasedProteins + WholeGrains + Starch + Eggs + ProcessedMeat + RedMeat + WhiteMeat +           
             Shellfish + Fish + Sweets + (1| ID) ,data = PhaseIBD_metadata_clean)
```

This is what I did, but the problem is that I don't have direction.

Could you please guide me on the appropriate statistical analysis or R techniques I should use to achieve this? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: If you want advice on how to model your data, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there. This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.